# Custom elements without shadow DOM: best way to get an element

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

Using Polymer, I learned to understand well the difference between light DOM (whatever is in the element) and local DOM (the "hidden" side of the story).

`<iron-form>` (which is used like `<form is="iron-form"></form>`) is a little different as it doesn't have local DOM.

Now I have a custom-made widget ([which is actually available in GitHub](https://github.com/mercmobily/hot-form-validator)) where you go:

```
    <hot-form-validator success-message="Record saved!">
      <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/stores/polymer">
        <paper-input required id="name" name="name" label="Your name"></paper-input>
        <paper-input required id="surname" name="surname" label="Your surname"></paper-input>
        <paper-button type="submit" raised on-click="_submit">Click!</paper-button>
      </form>
    </hot-form-validator>
```

Now, `hot-form-validator` needs to get the form, and then look -- within the form -- for a specific button (with `type=submit`). So, I have:
(remember that `this.form` is the form):

```
attached: function(){
  var paperButton = this.form.$$('paper-button[type=submit]');
  ...
}
```

It works, but it doesn't make sense that it does since `$$` should be only for local DOM, whereas paper-button is actually in the form's light DOM.

```
attached: function(){
  var paperButton = this.form.queryEffectiveChildren('paper-button[type=submit]');
```

This works, but I wonder if it's the best way to go.

Or... since there is no shadow DOM, should I simply no bother worrying about all this, and simply use DOM as always since there is no light/local DOM to deal with?

Comment: You're rigth, light DOM is just a synonym for normal DOM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#light-dom-children

If you add an `id` to the `<content id="someId"></content>` then you can use

```
var result = this.getContentChildren('#someId');
```

and then look up the desired element in the result.

You could for example create a specific `<content>` tag for the submit button like

```
<dom-module ...>
  <template>
    ...
    <content></content>
    <content id="submitButton" select="paper-button[type=submit]"></content>
    ...
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

and then get the element using

```
var submitButton = this.getContentChildren('#submitButton')[0];
```

This code is working

```
this.form.$$('paper-button[type=submit]');
```

because `this.$$` forwards to `querySelectorAll(...)` and in shady DOM encapsulation is just emulated and doesn't prevent `querySelectorAll(...)` to find other children than local DOM children.

You can also use

```
var submitButton = Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('paper-button[type=submit]');
```

Comment: I looked at the code, and `this.form.$$('paper-button[type=submit]');` works because it searches `this.root` (the local DOM), but since iron-form doesn't have shadow DOM, then `this === this.root` -- and voila' the `$$` notation works... right?

Comment: I didn't investigate that deep but `querySelectorAll()` can't distinguish between local DOM or light DOM and I'm pretty sure this is why it's working.